# Identify the city from a Microsoft Teams meeting's background

Tags: usa, identify-this

I was quite amazed of the image that appears in the back of my speaker on Microsoft Teams. Any chance to identify this city (actually skyline) or maybe even shooting location?

[image]

I know that the quality and resolution of this image is very low, but then again, the depicted skyscrapers seems to be very distinguish.

Unfortunately, Google Image Search brought no conclusive results, as it displayed a variety of skylines and skyscrapers around the world (which is also quite an achievement, given the resolution and quality of this image). I have no idea what other kind of searches to perform.

I am **assuming** that this is USA, so I am tagging this question like that. I may be all wrong though.

Comment: Do you have the full image or the name of the background series?

Comment: The (apparently) smaller one may be [Almas Tower in Dubai](https://www.skyscrapercenter.com/building/almas-tower/298) but I can’t quite find one matching the other one nearby

Comment: Almas Tower is at least very similar, but is also surrounded by other tall buildings, which are missing in the picture. It is difficult to say since the image quality is so poor, but to me, it does not look like a real photograph at all, but rather like a drawing or computer generated graphic. It might just be an imaginary view and not a real location.

Comment: isn't that the "One World Trade Center"? the one on the left

Comment: @NeanDerThal You had the same impression but I believe on One WTC the white lines are not that prominent. And of course it doesn’t quite look like Manhattan…

Comment: @jcaron I am a newbie in city / skyscraper identification, but I'd say that you hit the jackpot! If Tor-Einar Jarnbjo is right about surroundings of Almas Tower then either this is a very specific point of shooting or... Tor-Einar Jarnbjo is right about the fact that this is an artificial photo. No, nothing in better resolution is available, it was the biggest screenshot that I could take. Thank you all for all the attempts and participation. If that is the closest we can get then maybe someone crafts a guessing-like answer, so I can accept it and bring someone some rep? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s not a real city but rather a computer generated amalgam of different skyscrapers, which is why you’re struggling to identify the location.

Sources:

- Google Images fails to find the location
- So does Tineye
- So does ChatGPT
- The most prominent skyscraper is from Dubai but the rest of the skyline doesn’t match Dubai

Comment: Thank you! From what I can recall my 5-years-ago trip to UAE, I would risk that the other most prominent, most visible skyscraper is from Abu Dhabi (Emirates Towers?), but that might be a completely false shot. Thanks again for your effort.